# TipTap/ProseMirror wrap selection with arbitrary text

Tags: javascript, tiptap, prose-mirror

I am using TipTap to write markdown text (not html).

I'm doing this by not using any extensions like `Bold` and just doing them myself, and then using the `getText()` function.

All this works very well for my simple use case, even though I'm sure it's not ideal without using proper extensions etc.

(Note that I want all markdown to be visible, and not interpreted by the editor, which is why im doing it this way)

The problem is my wrapping/unwrapping code has some bugs, specifically related to going out of bounds.

The main time this occurs is if there is only a single word being highlighted, as well as multiple words but highlighting the last word

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nodeSize')
```

Is there a simpler way to do this, or what am I missing about my current implementation? I found it weird that the selections are not starting at `0` if i highlight just one word

```js
    const wrapUnwrap = marker => {
      const { state, view } = toRaw(editor.value);
      const { from, to } = state.selection;
      const len = marker.length;

      // exit if nothing selected
      if (from === to) {
        return;
      }

      // there is a current bug here where there are "node size" errors if you
      // try to select a single word and make it bold... as well as the last word
      let textBefore, textAfter;
      try {
        textBefore = state.doc.textBetween(from - len, from);
        textAfter = state.doc.textBetween(to, to + len);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
      }
      let tr = state.tr;

      if (textBefore === marker && textAfter === marker) {
        tr.delete(to, to + len);
        tr.delete(from - len, from);
      } else {
        tr.insertText(marker, to, to);
        tr.insertText(marker, from, from);
      }
      view.dispatch(tr);
    };

    const makeBold = () => {
      wrapUnwrap("**");
    };

    const makeItalic = () => {
      wrapUnwrap("*");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this...

```js
    const wrapUnwrap = marker => {
      const { state, view, from, to, tr } = buildTr();
      const len = marker.length;

      // exit if nothing selected
      if (from === to) {
        return;
      }

      let textBefore = "";
      let textAfter = "";

      if (from - len >= 1) {
        textBefore = state.doc.textBetween(from - len, from);
      }
      if (to + len <= state.doc.content.size) {
        textAfter = state.doc.textBetween(to, to + len);
      }

      if (textBefore === marker && textAfter === marker) {
        tr.delete(to, to + len);
        tr.delete(from - len, from);
      } else {
        tr.insertText(marker, to, to);
        tr.insertText(marker, from, from);
      }
      view.dispatch(tr);
    };

    const makeBold = () => {
      wrapUnwrap("**");
    };

    const makeItalic = () => {
      wrapUnwrap("*");
    };
```